# Redirect traffic to the domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an web server deployed through elastic beanstalk. I want to redirect my all requests to the my domain, consider it as example.com. So I used public DNS for the redirection but whenever my instance replaced by another instance through autoscaling, my domain example.com gives an error. What I have missed or wrong configured.

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We went through your issue and was able to conclude that you are facing a problem whenever a new instance gets launched through autoscaling.
 As you have deployed your environment through Elastic beanstalk we would suggest by using beanstalk URL as an alias in route 53. 
This would work seamlessly without any failure, even if your instance get launched by autoscaling. You can also try by setting Load Balancer URL in route53.